# ffmpeg giving Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to merge two video files into one using ffmpeg on Windows. The process has been proven to work over and over (with over 100 files merged together at some points) - but I have come across an input file that is causing the process to fail with the errors:

```
_[aac @ 00000142532f74c0] channel element 1.0 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 00000142532f74c0] channel element 1.0 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
[aac @ 00000142532f74c0] channel element 1.0 is not allocated
.
.
.
```

There seems to be 3 command line steps to get here, using a concats-inputs.dat file containing:

```
file E:/..../snippet A.mp4
file E:/..../snippet B.mp4
```

(Copies of these files can be found at https://filebin.net/77wbowvh7vbklkey/snippet_A.mp4 and https://filebin.net/77wbowvh7vbklkey/snippet_B.mp4)

Step 1 :

```
> ffmpeg-6.0-full_build/bin/ffmpeg -y -progress ".Default.mp4.progressinfo.dat" -vsync 0 -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:/...../concat-inputs.dat" -c:v copy -c:a copy -crf 0 -b:v 10M "E:/...../video.Default.mp4"
```

with the output....

```
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint

  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

-vsync is deprecated. Use -fps_mode

Passing a number to -vsync is deprecated, use a string argument as described in the manual.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001bf88ffe240] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'E:/...../concat-inputs.dat':

  Duration: N/A, start: -0.010667, bitrate: 20382 kb/s

  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20043 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264

  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 96000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 339 kb/s

    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Output #0, mp4, to 'E:/...../video.Default.mp4':

  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100

  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 10000 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264

  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 96000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 339 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
_[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001bf890653c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

[mp4 @ 000001bf89000580] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 180224, current: 180192; changing to 180225. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

frame=  210 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   11537kB time=00:00:04.21 bitrate=22433.7kbits/s speed=41.9x

video:11417kB audio:114kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.053312%
```

Step 2

```
> ffmpeg-6.0-full_build/bin/ffmpeg -y -progress ".Default.mp4.progressinfo.dat" -vsync 0 -f concat -safe 0 -i "E:/...../concat-inputs.dat" -c:v copy -c:a copy -crf 0 -b:v 10M "E:/...../audio.Default.wav"
```

which outputs...

```
ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint

  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

-vsync is deprecated. Use -fps_mode

Passing a number to -vsync is deprecated, use a string argument as described in the manual.

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000246d314e240] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

Input #0, concat, from 'E:/...../concat-inputs.dat':

  Duration: N/A, start: -0.010667, bitrate: 20382 kb/s

  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20043 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264

  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 96000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 339 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

[out#0/wav @ 00000246d31bd240] Codec AVOption b (set bitrate (in bits/s)) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.

Output #0, wav, to 'E:/...../audio.Default.wav':

  Metadata:

    ISFT            : Lavf60.3.100

  Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 96000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 339 kb/s

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    
_[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000246d3b009c0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter

[wav @ 00000246d3150580] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 180224, current: 180192; changing to 180224. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.

size=     114kB time=00:00:04.21 bitrate= 222.4kbits/s speed= 128x

video:0kB audio:114kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.102561%
```

Step 3

```
> ffmpeg-6.0-full_build/bin/ffmpeg -y -progress ".Default.mp4.progressinfo.dat" -i "E:/...../video.Default.mp4" -i "E:/...../audio.Default.wav" -crf 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac "E:/...../Default.mp4"
```

... which then gives the errors....

```
ffmpeg version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers

  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint

  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100    
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100    
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100    
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100    
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100    
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100    
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'E:/...../video.Default.mp4':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : isom    
    minor_version   : 512    
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41    
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100

  Duration: 00:00:04.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 22359 kb/s

  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 22178 kb/s, 49.80 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : VideoHandler    
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]    
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264

  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 96000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 221 kb/s (default)

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : SoundHandler    
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

[aac @ 000001425315e580] Multiple frames in a packet.

Input #1, wav, from 'E:/...../audio.Default.wav':

  Metadata:

    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100

  Duration: 00:00:04.22, bitrate: 221 kb/s

  Stream #1:0: Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 96000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 339 kb/s

Stream mapping:

  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)    
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))

Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Output #0, mp4, to 'E:/...../Default.mp4':

  Metadata:

    major_brand     : isom    
    minor_version   : 512    
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41

    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100

  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 22178 kb/s, 49.80 fps, 50 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : VideoHandler    
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]    
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264

  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 96000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 341 kb/s (default)

    Metadata:

      handler_name    : SoundHandler    
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]    
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 aac

frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
_[aac @ 00000142532f74c0] channel element 1.0 is not allocated

Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input    
[aac @ 00000142532f74c0] channel element 1.0 is not allocated
.
.
.
```

If I was to do this to merge `snippet B` with `snippet B` then it would work - it's something about `snippet A` that is causing the problem.

Is there any way to get around this... what is it about `snippet A` that is causing a problem... and is there a way to "normalize" it so that it can be merged as part of the "set".

Note, I just upgraded to ffmpeg6 after a previous version was giving the same problems - so I will also work on the deprecated messages when I can.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score -1):

Ok - I decided to investigate the input file using ffprobe and noticed that snippet B was stereo, but snippet A didn't show this.

With the help from a certain chatbot, I've been able to rebuild snippet A to make it stereo using the additional control of "`pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0`" on the -af option....

```
ffmpeg-6.0-full_build/bin/ffmpeg -y -progress ".progressinfo.dat"
      -i "E:/.../mono video.mp4"
      -ss 7.717 -to 9.589 -map_metadata -1
      -af "pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0,loudnorm=I=-16:LRA=11:TP=-1.5"
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                   <----- added additional stereo option
      -crf 0
      -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black,fps=50"
      -metadata service_provider="Test"
      -metadata service_name="mp4clipper" "E:/...../snippet A.mp4"
```

this seems to have resolved the problem